# How to get rid of endl from each Boost.Log line output?

Tags: endl

I am new to Boost.Log in my c++ program. I create a logger called "simlog" and then I use following line to output my log text:

BOOST_LOG( simlog ) << "some log info";

I don't want the default endl be appended to each of statement like this. I'd rather control whether to add a endl or not myself. How do I do that with Boost.Log? Is there a format setting to turn it on/off?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done with the out-of-the-box features of Boost.Log. However, you can define a custom sink backend, implement `do_consume` method and output log message there without trailing `\n`.

For more information on custom sink backends look here: [Writing your own sinks](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension.html#log.extension.sinks).